# Help with Users in Linux

Tags: 14.04, root, users, privileges, accounts

I need to separate the privileges of two users. One must be able to manage certain folders while the other should manage the rest.

My problem is that the root user has all the privileges and could eg change the owner of one of the portfolios managed by one of the users that I have mentioned.

How do I remove / disable the root user? Do you get it, it could be reactivated?

And how can I remove any user than can execute a command as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two users.

```
User A: can manage certain folders.
User B: can manage the rest of the folders.
```

Change the password to root so only you know it and no one but you can change permissions.

Do not give root privileges to either user and this way they will be unable to "reactive" it.

There is NO way to disable root...

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to achieve this. A root user can do anything. Even if a  directory or file is not accessible (like protected with a password or encrypted) for a root user he can delete it, overwrite it just by being root. Heck, he can even format the whole disk if needed.

Above makes 2 assumptions:

1. you are not the admin
2. you are talking about your main system

There is always at least one person that can use "sudo", or be "root" in your words. If that is you: fine, you can arrange those files for those users just by having 2 users, not in the same group and put permissions on their files and directories. If you are not... you are not going to be able to do this on your system itself.

Secondly, you *can* achieve what you want with an external disk. You can password protect that disk, or encrypt it, and unmount it when not immediately needed and even take it out of your machine when you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the root user. It is integral to how Ubuntu works. If you remove all users that can execute a root command, you are not able to install new software or update your computer. You might not be able to shutdown and you can't change some settings.

However, you can limit who has access to root. Any users you add should be "standard" users, not "admin".

With regards to the people who can manage certain folders, you need to add 2 users, each a standard account. Any folder these users create, only they will access it.

To change any folder that exists, you need to be root (ironically).

First, open `nautilus` as root, with this command:

```
sudo -i nautilus
```

Then, navigate top the folder, chose properties, then select the "Permissions" tab. Then chose the owner and change it to the person you want to have access. You may also want to change the group.